# Open Access db hosted online via DAO in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, dao

I've developed an Excel application in VBA with an Access database file back end (.accdb).  The connection is setup using DAO and the db is currently stored locally on my machine.  I'm curious though if I'll be able to host the db file on from a site like DropBox or Sharepoint365 where the path is an HTTP address?

Comment: You cannot use DAO to connect to an Access database using HTTP.  It's just not supported.  You need a file path (i.e. on your local computer or a networked file share on a LAN/WAN)

Comment: Based on my research that's what I was thinking, but wanted to double check.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have tried hosting the backend accdb on remote networks (i.e. on a WAN) and it does not work.

I think the problem is twofold. One problem is that there is an incredible amount of network traffic between the front and back ends, and two, network latency. Each back and forth is subject to network latency and there may be hundreds or even thousands of back and forth communications between the front and back end on every table/query/form/sheet/etc load. You end up with a front end that just hangs and is unusable.